# Laravel - Class 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, frameworks

On my website I am getting this error

```
Class 'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider' not found
```

I've searched everywhere and they tell me to composer install and add that package to my composer.json file

Whenever I do Composer install or Composer update I am presented with this:

```
 composer update
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Nothing to install or update
 Generating optimized autoload files
 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
 You made a reference to a non-existent script @/usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover
```

This is a fairly fresh install of laravel.

This is my composer.json file:
https://pastebin.com/0dMuKtM5

And this is my config/app.php
https://pastebin.com/HyxjkB1j

In reference you can see my website here: http://staging.creativehedgehog.co.uk/

Comment: Seems strange, any reason you're using a strict minor version of Laravel?  `5.6.12` instead of something like `5.6.*`?

Comment: It's possible that the file has been accidentally deleted (somehow). You could try deleting your vendor directory and then running composer install again.

Comment: Now deleting the vendor dir, and Devon i'll change it and try iit after the Com-install again

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove it composer.lock file and run composer install?

Comment: Can you check your laravel version and run this command; composer du

Answer (score 0):

Try using tinker on your project directory to find out if class can be shown

$ **php artisan tinker**

Psy Shell v0.9.8 (PHP 7.1.14 — cli) by Justin Hileman

> > > **show Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider**
> > >       (if error here, try to use string search below )

$ **grep -ri -l PaginationServiceProvider**

(if above grep worked, it will show a few files containing "PaginationServiceProvider" if still none after the grep then composer has not downloaded it.)